# Get datagrid values by row index for later use

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am trying to get the values of cells of a datagrid row I click on and store them for later use, but it seem I can't get it to work.

Clicking on the row should make a menu appear on which I can choose to do an action with those values.

This is what I've accomplished so far

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs x)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[x.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value != null) name = dataGridView1.Rows[x.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
            else if (dataGridView1.Rows[x.RowIndex].Cells["LastName"].Value != null) last = dataGridView1.Rows[x.RowIndex].Cells["LastName"].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                if (last != null && name != null)
                {
                    ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                    this.ContextMenu = cm;
                    cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("&Do something with those values in this row", new System.EventHandler(this.do_Action_with_values)));
                    cm.Show(this, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                }
                last = null;
                name = null;
            }
        }
```

Removing: if (last != null && name != null)

Will make the menu work, but the values aren't saved, them all are null.

Is there a properly way to store in strings all the column values for the row being clicked on?

Comment: This seems very complex.. Every time I've ever done this, I've just wired a click handler to the cm item and asked the grid for its selected rows/cells in the handler. Can't understand why you're using a mouse down to show the menu etc; you can just add a context menu and set it to belong to the grid..

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @CaiusJard. You have a mouse down handler that's responding to a right click (anywhere on the app), and a separate cell click handler that's setting values. The right click handler sets the values to null as well. Simplify this by putting all the code into one handler - Use CellMouseClick, which uses DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs, which contains both the cell details (row & col) and the mouse details (right mouse) for you to do what you wish with. Then you don't need to store name/last, you can just immediately read the cell and operate on it.

Comment: @Chris Could you provide me with an example? I've tried everything I could, that's what I could came up with so far

Answer (score 0):

Per request in comments, use `CellMouseClick` event and `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` to combine your handlers into one event handler that has all the properties you need.

Buyer beware, the code below was written outside of an IDE so there may be syntax/other errors.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right) return;
        int row = e.RowIndex;
        string name = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["Name"].Value;
        string last = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["LastName"].Value;
        if (name == null || name.Trim().Length == 0) return;
        if (last == null || last.Trim().Length == 0) return;
        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
        this.ContextMenu = cm;
        cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("&Do something with those values in this row", new System.EventHandler(this.do_Action_with_values)));
        cm.Show(this, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
```